# A module does not compile in a newer node.js version, any workarounds?

Tags: node.js, compilation, node-modules

my open-source project depends on a lemmatization module —
https://github.com/grachev/node-lemmer
— which needs to be compiled before it can run.

After updating to a newer version of `node.js` I can't run this module, because it needs to be re-compiled. Usually this was done when I simply did `npm install node-lemmer` however it is now not available in `npm` and I don't know how to compile it under that new node version and why I have to do it at all...

I tried running `npm rebuild` but it does not recompile – too many errors. The `issues` folder of that project on GitHub has the issue up already but there's no fix for it...

What could I do about it? Why do I need to recompile this module when I install a new version of `node`? Is there a workaround? Could I "trick" `node` or that module so it doesn't need to recompile? Or maybe it's possible to compile it manually?

...

**Some mode details:**

I used to run my project on node `0.8.3` vesion and then switched to the new `8.8.0` version. Now when I try to run my project under the new node version it doesn't start giving the following error:

```
module.js:641
return process.dlopen(module, path._makeLong(filename));
             ^

Error: Module did not self-register.
at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:641:18)
at Module.load (module.js:531:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:494:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:486:3)
at Module.require (module.js:556:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> 
(/path-to-my-project/node_modules/node-lemmer/lib/node-lemmer.js:1:82)
at Module._compile (module.js:612:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:623:10)
at Module.load (module.js:531:32)
```

which is an error I've seen before because my module could not be compiled.

my project is https://github.com/noduslabs/infranodus in case it helps to see the source code.

Comment: I'd suggest running your various modules through an ES6 lint program and it will probably point out some problems.

Comment: for now I had to install `nvm` and have several versions of `node` running on my machine, so my app is still usable.